Nuxt/Vue2 testing: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia
I'm converting a Nuxt/Vue2 app (which I didn't write) from Vuex to Pinia to prepare for upgrading Nuxt/Vue. After finishing the Vuex->Pinia migration the app runs but tests do not. Here's an example of a simple test I've changed from Vuex to Pinia:
import {createLocalVue, shallowMount} from "@vue/test-utils";
import { createTestingPinia } from '@pinia/testing';
import { PiniaVuePlugin } from 'pinia';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';

import FileOverlay from '@/components/files/index.vue'

const vuetify = new Vuetify();
const localVue = createLocalVue();
localVue.use(PiniaVuePlugin);

const file = {
    file_id: 1
}

describe("index.vue", function(){
    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = shallowMount(FileOverlay, {
            vuetify,
            localVue,
            propsData: {
                file: file
            },
            pinia: createTestingPinia()
        })
    });

    it("can be instantiated", () => {
        expect(wrapper.vm.$options.name).toMatch("FileOverlay");
    });

});

Running this test results in:
 ● Test suite failed to run

    []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Are you trying to use a store before calling "app.use(pinia)"?
    See https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/outside-component-usage.html for help.
    This will fail in production.

      93 | import { useFilesStore } from "@/stores/files";
      94 |
    > 95 | const files = useFilesStore();
         | ^
      96 |
      97 | export default {
      98 |   name: "FileOverlay",

      at useStore (node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.cjs:1743:19)
      at src/components/files/index.vue:95:1
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/components/files/index.vue:813:3)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/unit/components/files/index.spec.js:6:1)
      at TestScheduler.scheduleTests (node_modules/@jest/core/build/TestScheduler.js:333:13)
      at runJest (node_modules/@jest/core/build/runJest.js:404:19)
      at _run10000 (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:320:7)
      at runCLI (node_modules/@jest/core/build/cli/index.js:173:3)

But, as far as I can tell, my modifications to the test match what is specified in the documentation:
https://pinia.vuejs.org/cookbook/testing.html#Unit-test-components-Vue-2-
Can anyone explain what I have missed?
